# Can you fully charge a super capacitor at a lower voltage (than its max rating)

Tags: charging, supercapacitor

Is it possible to ***fully*** charge a super capacitor at voltage lower than its listed max rating?

Example: could I charge a 5,5V or 6V super capacitor using only 5V.
In case it matters, two example super capacitors that have a higher than 5V maximum rating.

VEC6R0 255QG; **6V**, 2.5F
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2149089.pdf
DDL105S05F1JRR; **5.5V**, 1F
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2368882.pdf

Gut feeling is that it's not, but I have not been able to verify this as of yet. It's probably too obvious and thus not stated..

Comment: E=CU^2/2 dictates you can’t since energy goes up with voltage squared.

Comment: Total charge, \$Q=CV\$, where \$V\$ is the final voltage across the capacitor, not the rated voltage.

Comment: It depends on what you understand by "fully".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Curd is right. "fully charged" bears no meaning.

Often, it just means that the capacitor voltage reached (of came very close to) the supply voltage. So, in this case, yes, you can fully charge it, at whatever voltage you want.

Now, if you want it to mean "store as much energy as it possibly could without exploding", then, no, and you'd better not even attempt to fully charge it.

In fact, you'd better ensure there is a small margin between the supply voltage and the capacitor rating. Using 6V/5.5V rated capacitors with a 5V supply seems reasonable (unless the 5V supply has a 20% tolerance, in which case you should use even higher ratings).

Comment: I'd want to utilize the supercap as much as I safely can. Hence my reference to a "full" charge. I like the idea of the safety margin.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "full charge".

- If you mean charge it up to its rating, then no, if you use a source voltage that's less than the rating, by definition you won't get a "full charge".
- If you mean charge it up to the source voltage, then yes, you can get arbitrarily close to "full charge".

You could use a DC-DC converter to increase the available source voltage to the rated voltage of the capacitor in order to get a full charge in the first sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I meant to charge to the maximum voltage of say 5.5V using less than 5V, but it's now clear to me that that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen folks ask this about capacitors before and had arguments with people about it. Some people seem to think that if the manufacturer rates his devices at 6V it must be safe to charge it to that level.

In practice you may get away with that most of the time. The manufacturer's procedures may provide some always positive tolerance on the part that will let it withstand a little more than the specified voltage. But there are zero guarantees of that.

Moreover, you already have tolerances in whatever you are charging the thing with. Your 6V may actually be 6.3V if your driver tolerance is 5%. As such you are venturing into unknown territory.

Further, the values specified by the manufacturer are given at a specific temperature, usually 25C. That value will vary with how cold or hot the device is, and you need to leave sufficient head-room in your design to allow for that.

Maximum ratings should always be treated as just that. It is a point where the supplier will no longer guarantee it will survive, but it is not a hard edge, it could fail anywhere around that point depending on tolerances and temperature.

If you have a bridge, and it is calculated it will not fail up to 10,000 Tonnes, you would be a fool to load it with 10,000 tonnes, especially on a really cold and windy day. An elevator has a maximum occupancy of say 10 people, but it will, or should be, designed with a factor of safety just in case those 10 folks are portly.

The same goes for electronic parts, components should always be de-rated in your design calculations. How much you de-rate depends on how accurately you can guarantee you can realistically drive them. Even then, subtract a bit more... just in case.